# Using a SQL server 2008R2 mdf file with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 on my local machine. I have an old version of my VS solution that uses an SQL Server 2008R2 file. Will this old version of my solution run on SQL Server 2012 or will I have to also install SQL Server 2008R2 again?

Comment: Why don't you try attaching the file with `sp_attach_db` and find out?

Comment: It will work, you should really do some research before posting a question here :) just an advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can backup your database from SQL Server 2008R2 and restore it in the new version (SQL Server 2012).
SQL Server upgrade your database automatically from older version to new version. But compatibility level of your database not changed. You can change compatibility of your database after restore by following query :

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

Also, if you detach your database and attached in new version of SQL Server, you database upgraded to new version too.